# java charAt() method and surrogate

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am writing java code and want to know why the output of this code is `x`. I was expecting `t` since it is the 5th letter.

```
public class StringBufferDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("ttsttxctlltnt");
        System.out.println(sb.charAt(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: `public char charAt(int index)` "Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() - 1. The first char value of the sequence is at index 0, the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: "t" is your sixth character and as java starts numberd from 0 so it will give u result like this

Answer (score 2):

It's because in java a `StringBuffer` object is indexed starting at 0. 1<sup>st</sup> char at position 0, 2<sup>nd</sup> char at position 1, etc...

```
String ------ "t t s t t x c t l l"
ArrayIndex --  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: No ... it is not because "computers start counting at zero".  It is because Java StringBuffers are indexed from zero.  1) Not all languages index from zero - Fortran and Pascal are counter-examples, and there are many others.  2) Not all indexable Java data structures are indexed from zero.  The JDBC APIs index from 1.

Answer (score 1):

The index starts from 0 and not 1. Hence in the string "ttsttxctlltnt", the character at position 5(0,1,2,3,4,5) i.e 'x' will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

the index starts at 0 so the the character at 5 th posistion is x ... if u want t as the output then try the following

```
 System.out.println(sb.charAt(4));
```